# how to apply if-else for a complex JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, if-statement, jmeter

here is the Sample Json:-

```
[
    {
    "index": 0,
    "object": {

    "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX",

    "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet",

    "createdBy": "abc@xyz.com",

    "createdTime": 1531431176965,

    "updatedBy": "abc@xyz.com",

    "updatedTime": 1531431177691,

    "attributes": {

        "Weight": [

            {

                "label": "5 lbs",

                "value": {

                    "PetWeightMeasurement": [

                        {

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "5",

                        }

                    ],

                    "PetWeightUOM": [

                        {

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "lbs",

                            "lookupCode": "lbs",

                        }

                    ]

                },

                "ov": true,

                "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Weight/1AeFvD8Kj"

            }

        ],

        "Identifiers": [

            {

                "label": "5155445576",

                "value": {

                    "Type": [

                        {

                            "ov": false,

                            "value": "CRMO_Pet_Id",

                        }

                    ],

                    "ID": [

                        {

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "5155445576",

                        }

                    ]

                },

                "ov": true,

                "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Identifiers/1AeFvCrHh"

            }

        ],

        "Vaccination": [

            {

                "label": "Bordatella - 2018-10-26",

                "value": {

                    "Type": [

                        {

                            "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/Type",

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "Bordatella",

                            "lookupCode": "4",

                            "lookupRawValue": "Bordatella",

                            "lookupAttributes": [

                                {

                                    "name": "Sort Order",

                                    "value": "3"

                                }

                            ],

                            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr/Type/1AeFvA2X7"

                        }

                    ],

                    "ExpirationDate": [

                        {

                            "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/ExpirationDate",

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "2018-10-26",

                            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr/ExpirationDate/1AeFvA6nN"

                        }

                    ]

                },

                "ov": true,

                "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr"

            },

            {

                "label": "Distemper - 2018-10-25",

                "value": {

                    "Type": [

                        {

                            "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/Type",

                            "ov": true,

                            "value": "Distemper",

                            "lookupAttributes": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Sort Order",
                                    "value": "4"
                                }
                            ],
                            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9YhJ/Type/1AeFv9cxZ"
                        }
                    ],....
```

My question: I was able to get the value of "$..Vaccination..value.Type..value" as "Bordatella" so that works fine. However what I now want is that if the value is 'Bordatella' then I want to extract the "value" under "ExpirationDate". Can someone please help me how I can extract that "value" under "ExpirationDate" ? I am not sure if I need to do that with some custom Groovy code of using jmeter's if controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please revise the sample data so that it is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to run [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) queries from within Java - e.g.

- https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq
- https://github.com/arakelian/java-jq (available from Maven Central)
- Java Native Access wrapper https://github.com/bskaggs/jjq . Supported platform is Linux only.

Assuming the sample input has been revised in the obvious way to make it valid JSON, the following jq filter will produce the output as shown:

```
.[].object.attributes.Vaccination[].value
| select(.Type[].value == "Bordatella")
| .ExpirationDate[].value
```

Output:

```
"2018-10-26"
```

### Alternative

Here's a jq filter that is agnostic about the relative location of the "Vaccination" object:

```
  ..
  | objects
  | select(has("Vaccination"))
  | .Vaccination[].value?
  | select(.Type[].value == "Bordatella")
  | .ExpirationDate[].value
```

Comment: so is that custom code i need to write in Jmeter? cannot use the built-in If Controller ?

Comment: would this work if I used this in the If Controller block? If not please suggest any corrections here

$..Vaccination..value[?(@.Type..value == ‘Bordatella’)].ExpirationDate..value

Answer (score 0):

Given the following JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "object": {
      "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX",
      "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet",
      "createdBy": "a...@xyz.com",
      "createdTime": 1531431176965,
      "updatedBy": "a...@xyz.com",
      "updatedTime": 1531431177691,
      "attributes": {
        "Weight": [
          {
            "label": "5 lbs",
            "value": {
              "PetWeightMeasurement": [
                {
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "5"
                }
              ],
              "PetWeightUOM": [
                {
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "lbs",
                  "lookupCode": "lbs"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ov": true,
            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Weight/1AeFvD8Kj"
          }
        ],
        "Identifiers": [
          {
            "label": "5155445576",
            "value": {
              "Type": [
                {
                  "ov": false,
                  "value": "CRMO_Pet_Id"
                }
              ],
              "ID": [
                {
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "5155445576"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ov": true,
            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Identifiers/1AeFvCrHh"
          }
        ],
        "Vaccination": [
          {
            "label": "Bordatella - 2018-10-26",
            "value": {
              "Type": [
                {
                  "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/Type",
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "Bordatella",
                  "lookupCode": "4",
                  "lookupRawValue": "Bordatella",
                  "lookupAttributes": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sort Order",
                      "value": "3"
                    }
                  ],
                  "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr/Type/1AeFvA2X7"
                }
              ],
              "ExpirationDate": [
                {
                  "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/ExpirationDate",
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "2018-10-26",
                  "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr/ExpirationDate/1AeFvA6nN"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ov": true,
            "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9yGr"
          },
          {
            "label": "Distemper - 2018-10-25",
            "value": {
              "Type": [
                {
                  "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Pet/attributes/Vaccination/attributes/Type",
                  "ov": true,
                  "value": "Distemper",
                  "lookupAttributes": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sort Order",
                      "value": "4"
                    }
                  ],
                  "uri": "entities/oAFpSUX/attributes/Vaccination/1AeFv9YhJ/Type/1AeFv9cxZ"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).get(0).get('object').get('attributes').get('Vaccination').each { vaccination ->
       if (vaccination.get('value').get('Type').get(0).get('value').equals('Bordatella')) {
           def expirationDate = vaccination.get('value').get('ExpirationDate').get(0).get('value')
           log.info('ExpirationDate: ' + expirationDate)
           vars.put('ExpirationDate', expirationDate)
       }
   }
   ```
3. If everything goes well (your JSON response matches the Groovy code) the ExpirationDate will be:

   - printed to *jmeter.log* file
   - stored as `${ExpirationDate}` JMeter Variable

Demo:

[image: JMeter Extract Value from JSON with Groovy]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)